# Foreign key one to many (postgresql, php, yii2)

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

Heloo,

I just beginner with yii2 and postgresql.
I have problem like this:

First table:

```
tbl_printer (PK dept_id and id)

| dept_id | id | name |
```

Second table

```
tbl_printer_group (PK dept_id and id)

| dept_id | id | printer1 | printer2 | printer3 |
```

`printer1`, `printer2`, `printer3` data/value from `tbl_printer.id`

I want to 'DISALLOWED to DELETE' `tbl_printer` IF printer (id) STILL IN USE at `tbl_printer_group` (printer1,printer2,printer3). If not wrong foreign key, one to one from parent to child, but this one to many.

How to solve this problem, I'm using php, yii2 and postgresql.

Thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key is added through [migration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html) with help of [addForeignKey()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#addForeignKey%28%29-detail) method:

```
$this->addForeignKey(
    'name_of_foreign_key_constraint',
    'products',
    'category_id',
    'products_categories',
    'id',
    'CASCADE',
    'CASCADE'
);
```

The last two options is for `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` accordingly.

> Most DBMS support these options: `RESTRICT`, `CASCADE`, `NO ACTION`,
>   `SET DEFAULT`, `SET NULL`.

Note that you can specify arrays instead of `category_id` and `id` columns:

> If there are multiple columns, separate them with commas or use an
>   array.

Framework provides most used and needed methods for that, but remember that you can always execute custom SQL inside a migration with just writing:

```
$this->execute('YOUR CUSTOM SQL QUERY');
```

Comment: Thank you arogachev, so I must write code in php. I think we can use database features like foreign key....Thank you very much for your response

Comment: @mltobing We can use methods in migrations for most common database features, but framework can't provide abstractions for all specific database features, for example PostgreSQL.